# Cannot convert 'char*(*)[6]' to 'char***' for argument '2' to 'void prac(int*,char***)'

Tags: c++, arrays, c++11, pointers

I see this error when compile my program:

```
Cannot convert 'char*(*)[6]' to 'char***' for argument '2' to 'void prac(int*,char***)'
```

How can I fix the code ? Please help me.

Code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void prac(int *argc, char **b[])
{
//body
//
}

int main()
{

     char *ptr_array[] = {"ssl","0.0.0.0","","tcp","0.0.0.0","8080"};
prac(&argc, &ptr_array);   

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Don't use so many pointers.

Comment: 1 * for string, 2 * for string array.

Comment: Why do you want to take the address of the ptr_array?

Comment: Arrays are not pointers. Arrays of arrays, arrays of pointers, pointers to arrays, and pointers to pointers are all different. Don't use any of them. std::vector and std::string and pass by reference are your friends.

Comment: I have to change daemon source code and pass to function with these arguments. Befor, I call program with main(int argc, char *argv[]), But, I wish assign arguments in program body.

Comment: `&argc, &ptr_array` is **almost certainly** going to lead to errors. If you insist on writing C, you will have to pass correct array sizes. Do what @n.m. suggests, and re-write with idiomatic C++

Comment: [Three star programmer detected!](http://wiki.c2.com/?ThreeStarProgrammer)

Answer (score 1):

`char *` is used to point to a string since only address of first char is needed because they are continous memory locations for arrays.
Therefore for and array of strings it can be an array of char pointers. aka `char **b` Only 2 not 3. or `char *b[]`

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void prac(int *argc, char **b)
{
//body
//
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

    char *ptr_array[] = {"ssl","0.0.0.0","","tcp","0.0.0.0","8080"};
    prac(&argc, ptr_array);   

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: tnx alot JoshKisb for this solution!

Comment: I predict that the body of `prac` will assume the length of `b` is contained in `*a`, which will **most likely** not be the case here

Answer (score 1):

The answer is already presented for you in the arguments passed to main

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
```

As `char* argv[]` is an array of the command line arguments passed to the program. Change the argument in the prac declaration to match that like so

```
int prac(int* argc, char* b[])
```

Also you should be getting compilation warnings stating:

> ```
> warning: ISO C++ forbids converting a string constant to ‘char*’
> ```

to avoid this set `ptr_array` to `const char*` and likewise for `const char* b[]` in `prac()`.

Answer (score 0):

The first answer is probably what you want.  If you really want to send the arguments as you have shown, the compiler message actually tells you how to declare the parameters:

```
void prac(int *argc, char *(*b)[6])
```

If you're thinking the extra layer of pointers will allow prac to change the array, it won't actually buy you much.  It lets prac change the value of argc in the main, but it can't change the actual size of the array.